# The probability to stop a process

Tags: probability, statistics

A company manufactures cylinders with diameters that follow a normal distribution with an average of 50mm and a standard deviation of 2.5mm. The diameters of a sample of 4 cylinders are measured every hour. The sample mean is used to decide whether or not the manufacturing process is operating satisfactorily. It applies the following decision rule: If the average sample diameter of 4 cylinders is equal to 53.7mm or more, or equal to 46.3mm or less, should stop the process. If the average diameter is between 46.3mm and 53.7mm, the process should continue.

(a) What is the probability to stop the process if the average μ process continues 50mm?

(b) What is the process likely to continue if the process mean move to μ =
53.7?

Guys, could you give me a hint? I have no idea how to start it?

Answer (score 1):

For this exercise you have a random variable X, which represent the diameter from a cylinder. This r. v. is normal distributed with average 50 mm and standard deviation 2.5 mm, so 
$$X \sim N(50,2.5^2).$$
Now you look at 4 cylinders and compute the average (i call it Z):
$$Z = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=1}^4 X_i$$
With $\alpha + \beta X \sim N(\alpha + \beta \mu, \beta^2\sigma^2)$ for a normal distributed r. v. with expectation $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ and the $X_i \overset{i.i.d}{\sim} X$ you get:
$$Z \sim N\left(\frac{1}{4} \sum_{i=1}^4 \cdot 50, \frac{1}{4^2}\sum_{i=1}^4 2.5^2\right) = N\left(50,\frac{2.5^2}{4}\right) = N\left(50,\left(\frac{2.5}{2}\right)^2\right)$$
Now compute the probability for (a):

(a)

The process continues if $Z \in [46.3, 53.7]$ so the probability is
$$P(Z \in [46.3, 53.7]) = P(Z \geq 46.3) - P(Z \geq 53.7) $$
The probability that the process stops is now 
$$1 - P(Z \in [46.3, 53.7]).$$
You just have to compute the probabiltys $P(Z \geq 53.7)$ and $P(Z \geq 46.3)$.

The first probability gives
$$P(Z\geq46.3) = 1 - \underbrace{P(Z\leq46.3)}_{=\phi^{-1}\left(\frac{46.3-50}{2.5/2}\right) = \phi^{-1}\left(-2.96\right)} = 1 - \phi^{-1}\left(-2.96\right)$$
The $\phi^{-1}\left(-2.96\right)$ can now seen in the table for standard normal distributet random variables.

The other probability is due to the symmetry from the normal distribution on $\mu$
$$P(Z\geq 53.7) = 1 - \phi^{-1}(2.96)$$

With R I get $$P(Z \geq 46.3) - P(Z \geq 53.7) = 0.9969236 \approx 99.69\%$$

(The R command was `1-pnorm(-2.96) - (1-pnorm(2.96))`)

And the probability to stop the process is 
$$1 - 99.69\% \approx 0.31\%$$

(b)

In my opinion you have to do the same like in (a) but now for the probability that the process continuous and here

$$X \sim N(53.7,2.5^2)$$

With that you get
$$Z \sim N\left(53.7, \left(\frac{2.5}{2}\right)^2\right)$$

And concerning on that the probability to don't stop the process is
\begin{align*}
P(Z \geq 46.3) - P(Z \geq 53.7) &= 1-\phi^{-1}\left(\frac{46.3-53.7}{1.25}\right) - \left(1-\phi^{-1}\left(\frac{53.7-53.7}{1.25}\right)\right) = \\
&= \phi^{-1}(0) - \phi^{-1}(-7.4) \approx\\
&\approx 0.5
\end{align*}

This is because $\phi^{-1}(-7.4) \approx 0$ and $\phi^{-1}(0) = 0.5$.

I hope i didn't miss something. :)

Comment: How can I know P(Z>=53.7) and P(Z>=46.3)?

Comment: You know how Z is distributed. One opinion is to standardize Z and then you have a standard normal distributed random variable. That means you can look in a table and look for the value $P(Z \geq z) = \phi^{-1}\left(\frac{z - \mu_Z}{\sigma_Z}\right)$ (because $\frac{Z-\mu_Z}{\sigma_Z} \sim N(0,1)$). The second way is to calculate the probabilty with a sofware like R. For this oportunity you have to use the command `pnorm(z,50,2.5/4)`.

Comment: I was seeing in this table and I cannot find it, for example. http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~athienit/Tables/Ztable.pdf

Comment: Doesn't need z be smaller than 3?

Comment: (53.7-50)/2.5= 1.48?

Comment: Wow sorry I made a horrible mistake! The probability $P(Z \leq z) = \phi^{-1}\left(\frac{z-\mu_z}{\sigma_Z}\right)$. To calculate $P(Z \geq z)$ you need $P(Z \geq z) = 1 - P(Z \leq z)$ (you can write less or equal because it's a continuous random variable). The value $z$ could be every number $\in \mathbb{R}$ also because $Z$ is a continuous random variable. Also the r. v. $Z$ is different distributed. I make the changes in my solution, sorry for that. I write it a step clearer. (shame on me :( )